# printf() seemingly not working as expected

Tags: c, printf

Printf() on following code may behave incorrectly on some machine (including mine).

```
printf("\n number of factor %d\n", sum); 
fflush(stdout);
if(sum == 0) 
{   
   printf("\n The  number %d is prime", p);
}
```

The code first prints out the variable ``sum'', and if, the sum is zero then it prints out the number.

While first `printf` prints correctly but second `printf` statement doesn't print. 
Am I missing something here?

Comment: the sum might not be zero! So therefore it does not print

Comment: Are you sure that sum is not equal to 0?

Comment: Yes. The rest of the code example. What is sum?

Comment: If the second `printf` doesn't print, then you have discovered a bug in your compiler. More likely `sum` is non-zero.

Comment: You can check the value of sum right before the if statement to check if it is actually 0.

Comment: "printf() not doing its job". You need to have a little faith on the primitives you use...

Comment: I'm printing the sum right before the "if" block. And it does print sum variable to 0.

Comment: Is `sum` of type `int`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 1):

You are either missing a newline at the end of the `printf` format string, or another call to `fflush`

#### example why `fflush` is important

```
// file exflu.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   int i=0;
   printf ("without newline from %s", argv[0]);
   // add perhaps a fflush(stdout); here
   sleep(5);
   scanf ("%d", &i);
   printf(" i=%d\n", i);
   return 0;
}
```

Observe the above program with and without `fflush`; without it, the message appears after five seconds (because the `scanf` is probably doing a `fflush(NULL)` implicitly).

Comment: Not flushing won't prevent a message from showing up though. It just won't show right away.

Comment: Except if the program don't exit immediately, then the output is still inside the `FILE` internal buffer. For instance, if something makes a read, the output won't appear before without `fflush` calls.

Comment: I've never seen what you describe. I never call `fflush` in my simple C programs. Output always appears on the console when the program terminates. Do you really think this is a more likely explanation than sum being non-zero?

Comment: Try the example I just added.

Comment: I edited my example (and discovered that `scanf` might do a `fflush(NULL)` with it).

Comment: \n at the end of printf did the job. Thanks.

Comment: A good beginner's rule is that almost every `printf` should end by `\n` when you want the output to be seen.